# How do i stop 'sign up' from triggering onAuthStateChange in javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

When I sign up a user it automatically signs in the user in Firebase.
I have tried using 
`var user = firebase.auth().getCurrentUser() if (user) then ...`   (something like that) to replace the onAuthStateChange, but it does not work.

Is there any solutions to this? I am doing it both in plain Javascript and React-native.

Answer (score 0):

You can't stop sign up from triggering `onAuthStateChanged` listener. Sign up also signs in the user and this is why the listener gets triggered. You also need that listener to properly detect the initial auth state as well as subsequent sign in/out events.